# W3 automatic slideshow 2 on same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need 2 automatic slideshow on one page, but there is a problem.
I use W3 slideshow, but if i make automatic they just after one rotation or just stop show up.

Here is code.
I try to change, but i not sure what i do wrong. If you can help me.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides", "mySlides2");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none;}
.mySlides2 {display:none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

</head>

<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
<h2 class="w3-center">Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="img_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="img_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some edits and now your code [is working](https://jsfiddle.net/vqr1t04k/) !

You don't want to use only one index, you want to use one index for each slideshow.

For each call to `carousel()` you will need to stop displaying the current img (n°`[x|y]Index`), and display the next img (n°`[x|y]Index`).

With this function, you can add different numbers of images in each slideshow (in my example, `mySlides` displays 3 images and `mySlides2` has 4).

```js
let xIndex = 0;
let yIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); 
  let y = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2"); 
  
  x[xIndex].style.display = "none";
  y[yIndex].style.display = "none";
  
  xIndex = (xIndex+1)%x.length;
  yIndex = (yIndex+1)%y.length;
  
  if (xIndex > x.length)
    xIndex = 1;
  
  if (yIndex > y.length)
   yIndex = 1;
  
  x[xIndex].style.display = "block";  
  y[yIndex].style.display = "block";  

 setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```html
<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div style="width:150px; height:150px; overflow: hidden;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" style="width:100%; display: none;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="width:100%; display: none;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/" style="width:100%; display: none;">
</div>
<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div style="width:150px; height:150px; overflow: hidden;">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/" style="width:100%; display: none;">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/400/" style="width:100%; display: none;">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" style="width:100%; display: none;">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/300/" style="width:100%; display: none;">
</div>
```